# In Django Admin, how do you have cascaded InlineModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a list of restaurants (e.g. McDonalds, etc), with menus (e.g Lunch Menu, Dinner Menu), submenus (e.g. Appetizers, Sandwidches, etc.) and dishes (Angus Burger, Chicken Burger, etc.)

They are all linked by foreign keys.

Is there a way, so that in the Restaurant admin, I have Menu as a tabular inline, with a link to go edit that menu (in it's own admin page, not inline) so that there I can display the submenus inline with the menu admin. Each submenu has a link to edit that submenu item (in it's own admin page, not inline) so that there I can display the dishes inline.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append some links like in the Restaurant change view, you don't really need to use an inline as this provides a form for changing data. I would probably override change_view in RestaurantAdmin to get a list of the related menus and pass it as an extra_context. And then override the model specific change_form.html template to render the menu links.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add field to your `MenuInline` that links to the `change_form` of each menu?

This can be done using [`read_only`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) fields.

First i would add a method to your Menu model that creates the link to the model's `change_form` in the admin. See [Reversing admin URLs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) for some pointers.

You should end up with something similar to this:

```
def get_menu_admin_page(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse('admin:yourapp_menu_change',
                                             args=(self.pk,)), self.menu_title)

get_menu_admin_page.allow_tags = True
```

Now you can add this method to your `InlineAdmin`.

```
class MenuInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Menu
    fields = ('menu_title', 'get_menu_admin_page')
    readonly_fields = ('get_menu_admin_page',)
```

Now your `TabularInline` should contain a link to the `change_view` for each individual menu.

Comment: If you don't want to add get_menu_admin_page to your model you can add it directly to the InlineAdmin. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249186/django-admin-tabularinline-is-there-a-good-way-of-adding-a-custom-html-column/5355985#5355985